# How do I change the position of the buttons in responsive design?

Tags: html, css, position, media-queries

I am trying to change the positions of the buttons which will scale down to mobile relative to the image div. I tried position/absolute; but it didn't take effect. Neither did the buttons stay relative inside the image div. I am not sure if the media queries will do the job or not. Any solutions?

```
<div id="hero-wrapper" class="main_wrapper hero">
<img src="images/home-hero-image.jpg" alt="fruute">
<div class="herobuttons"><div id="hero-shop-cookies" class="hero-btn"><a href="gourmet-cookies/index.html" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Homepage', 'Body', 'Cookies']);">shop cookies</a></div>
   <div id="hero-shop-gifts" class="hero-btn"><a href="gift-baskets/index.html" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Homepage', 'Body', 'Gifts']);">shop gifts</a></div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#hero-shop-cookies {
   top: 398px;
   left: 550px;
}

#hero-shop-gifts {
  top: 398px;
   left: 715px;
}

.main_wrapper hero{
    width: 100%;
}

#hero-wrapper{
   position: relative;
}

.hero-wrapper > .hero-btn a{
  position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 15px;
   bottom: 20px;
   top: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
#nav-menu{
    display: none;
}

#navigation li, #navigation a{
    float:left;
}

.main_wrapper hero, .hero-btn{
    width: 100%;
}

.herobuttons{
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

  #slideshow-area{
     width: 300px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Mobile is starting from smaler media query, like:

`@media (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 500px) { /* Mobile only */`

Answer (score 0):

Change min-width: 768px; to max-width: 768px;